# how to connect fuelphp wih oracle?

Tags: php, oracle, fuelphp

I am new in oracle and fuelphp, simple question, how to set connection fuelphp framework with oracle DB, documentation only for mysql and postgresql :

```
// a MySQL driver configuration
'development' => array(
'type'           => 'mysqli',
'connection'     => array(
    'hostname'       => 'localhost',
    'port'           => '3306',
    'database'       => 'fuel_db',
    'username'       => 'your_username',
    'password'       => 'y0uR_p@ssW0rd',
    'persistent'     => false,
    'compress'       => false,
),
'identifier'     => '`',
'table_prefix'   => '',
'charset'        => 'utf8',
'enable_cache'   => true,
'profiling'      => false,
'readonly'       => false,
),

// a PDO driver configuration, using PostgreSQL
'production' => array(
'type'           => 'pdo',
'connection'     => array(
    'dsn'            => 'pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=fuel_db',
    'username'       => 'your_username',
    'password'       => 'y0uR_p@ssW0rd',
    'persistent'     => false,
    'compress'       => false,
),
'identifier'     => '"',
'table_prefix'   => '',
'charset'        => 'utf8',
'enable_cache'   => true,
'profiling'      => false,
'readonly'       => array('slave1', 'slave2', 'slave3'),
)
```

how to connect with oracle? thank you

Answer (score 0):

Working from the PostgreSQL PDO example you posted I would try this:

```
'production'     => array(
'type'           => 'pdo',
'connection'     => array(
    'dsn'            => 'oci:dbname=//hostname:port/database',
    'username'       => 'your_username',
    'password'       => 'y0uR_p@ssW0rd',
    'persistent'     => false,
    'compress'       => false,
),
'identifier'     => '"',
'table_prefix'   => '',
'charset'        => 'utf8',
'enable_cache'   => true,
'profiling'      => false,
'readonly'       => false
)
```

Just be sure that you've [correctly installed & configured](http://php.net/manual/en/oci8.requirements.php) the PHP OCI drivers.